# oData Incorrect PageSize

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, odata

I am trying to expose my tables through oData and I have a Pagesize of 100. I also have other query properties.

```
EnableQuery(PageSize = 100, MaxNodeCount = 1000, EnableConstantParameterization = true, HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.Default, 
        MaxTop = 1000, MaxExpansionDepth = 1, MaxAnyAllExpressionDepth = 1)
```

However when I try to capture the query on the profiler surprisingly i see the page size as 101. I was expecting to see it as 100.

What am I missing here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one more than page size as we need to know whether the collection was truncated or not while generating next page links.
Check
[this](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/Expressions/SelectExpandBinder.cs#L479-L497) and [this](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Query/TruncatedCollectionOfT.cs) code.

It is by design.